# How to assign values with respective variable name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

How to create a new column by using loop to assign different number with respective string in data frame? For example:['buy','sell',hold'] to [-1,+1,0] ?

This is my column and i wish to add a new column

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Rv3c.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're just looking for Pandas' [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) method:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     'stock': ['AAAA', 'BBBB', 'CCCC', 'DDDD', 'EEEE', 'FFFF'],
...     'disposition': ['buy', 'buy', 'sell', 'hold', 'buy', 'sell']})
>>> df['change'] = df.disposition.map({'buy': -1, 'sell': +1, 'hold': 0})
>>> df
  disposition stock  change
0         buy  AAAA      -1
1         buy  BBBB      -1
2        sell  CCCC       1
3        hold  DDDD       0
4         buy  EEEE      -1
5        sell  FFFF       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple assignment statements. (I'm not sure what you meant by adding a new column, so perhaps you could illustrate the data structure you're thinking about.)

Example:

```
    >>> d = {'buy': [1], 'sell': [3], 'hold': [5]}
    >>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    >>> d['buy'],d['sell'],d['hold'] = -1, 1, 0
    >>> print (d)
        {'sell': 1, 'hold': 0, 'buy': -1}
```